# How to point some, but not all of domain to a different nameserver

Tags: redirect, dns, http-status-code-301, cname, forwarding

My client's domain registration is with Network Solutions, but the files, ftp and cPanel for their current site are with another company and are not accessible to me.

We are building a new site at a different domain name and will point the old url to it. The complication is a section of the old site that the client wants to remain at the current url for the next 5 months.

In other words, I want to redirect current-site.com to new-site.com, except for everything in current-site.com/one-section/ which needs to be viewable at that old address.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking this is what you are looking for. I have done it in Godaddy using this instruction on the link which it will hopefully give you a better idea on how to do it. It's a very easy process. You can find the IP of the website you want to redirect to on the left side fo the cpanel or you can do it via command line entering the following: on windows click win key + R type cmd inside of cmd type ping and the address e.g ping www.google.com

https://www.hostmysite.com/support/legacy-control-panel/dns/domain_point/

Comment: I understand how to point a domain, but I don't know how to exclude part of a domain from the pointing. Please re-read my question.